# Google One Tap Sign In for subdomain

Tags: subdomain, google-one-tap

i want to ask about implement google one tap sign in, into subdomain

first of all, i already add one tap into main domain
let's say, https://www.example.com. and this domain is registered on google console

i wanna put the one tap sign in into my subdomain, let's say : https://sub1.example.com

on the documentary, they said use this code

You can use the data-state_cookie_domain configuration parameter to change the state cookie domain. The following code example shows how to set the data-state_cookie_domain parameter:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
     data-auto_select="true"
     data-state_cookie_domain="parentdomain.com"
     data-login_uri="https://login.parentdomain.com/your_login_endpoint">
</div>
```

I already trying the code, but it not successfull.
Error message is still same, The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.

How can I implement this into subdomain?

Thanks